# How to know if Google Chrome has finished synchronizing?

Tags: google-chrome, sync

I use a dual boot machine, and have setup chrome browser to sync my bookmarks, apps and other data.

Now, if I boot open windows, add some bookmarks, install chrome app/extension,etc then how do I know if everything has been synchronized?

Disabling and enabling the sync is not the efficient option every time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can type `chrome://sync-internals` in the omnibox. It lets you view internal and technical data about your connection to the Google Cloud. It is actually intended for developers, but it can also be used to know the status of the sync.

In the **About** tab, you can find "**Last Synced**", if it shows "**Just Now**" you can be sure that the sync process completed just now, and be sure that everything has been synced.
There is one more field "**Sync Cycle Ongoing**" which shows the status of sync, if its true it means the sync is being done and you should wait.

You can experiment with it by adding/removing a bookmark and observe the changes on the page, this way you will be able to better understand the status of the sync and information displayed at page.

[Source](http://www.thechromesource.com/looking-at-chromes-sync-internals-page/)

Comment: Seems as though the field "Syncing" is depracated in Version 81.0.4044.113

Comment: I guess it is `Sync Cycle Ongoing` now